# Finding no. of new or on going trip instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a very large sql table, there are millions of datetimes given. How can I find out at any given second how many rides are in progress and how many rides have started?
Edit: 
Columns in table:-

1. Trip start datetime
2. Trip end datetime
3. No. Of travellers
4. Total income (taxes, and fare etc all inclusive)
5. Trip distance

This is the schema and every column is in the same table. 
There are no unique car ID given so it’s incredibly tough for me to calculate how many total cars are there based on this data.

I hope this information is sufficient.

Comment: table names? column names? example data? what have you tried so far?  What doesn't work?  Error messages?  where datetime between thissecond and thissecond plus one second.

Comment: Since you gave us zero in the way of details the only answer that is valid here is "by using a query". I doubt that is what you are looking for. But without some kind of details nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First for an in-memory calendar table granular to the second. This query return every hour/min/second between @startdate and @enddate

```
DECLARE 
  @startdate DATETIME = '2019-01-01 06:00:00.000',
  @enddate   DATETIME = '2019-01-01 07:00:00.000';

WITH 
E1 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS x(x)),
E3 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c),
iTally(N) AS
(
  SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@startdate,@enddate)+1) 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1
  FROM E3 a, E3 b
),
Calendar AS
(
  SELECT DT = DATEADD(SECOND,i.N,@startdate)
  FROM       iTally AS i
)
SELECT c.DT FROM Calendar AS c
```

**Returns:**

```
DT
-----------------------
2019-01-01 06:00:00.000
2019-01-01 06:00:01.000
2019-01-01 06:00:02.000
2019-01-01 06:00:03.000
...
2019-01-01 06:59:56.000
2019-01-01 06:59:57.000
2019-01-01 06:59:58.000
2019-01-01 06:59:59.000
2019-01-01 07:00:00.000
```

We can use this table for a LEFT join to your table with information about "rides"

```
-- Date Boundary Parameters
DECLARE 
  @startdate DATETIME = '2019-01-01 06:00:00.000',
  @enddate   DATETIME = '2019-01-01 07:00:00.000';

-- Easily consumable sample data
DECLARE @ride TABLE 
(
  rideId     INT identity,
  RideStart  DATETIME NOT NULL,
  RideEnd    DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT @ride (RideStart,RideEnd) VALUES 
('2019-01-01 06:00:01.000', '2019-01-01 06:33:12.000'),
('2019-01-01 06:00:04.000', '2019-01-01 06:14:19.000'),
('2019-01-01 06:02:15.000', '2019-01-01 06:05:48.000'),
('2019-01-01 06:02:47.000', '2019-01-01 06:04:21.000');

-- Solution
WITH 
E1 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS x(x)),
E3 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c),
iTally(N) AS
(
  SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@startdate,@enddate)+1) 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1
  FROM E3 a, E3 b
),
Calendar AS
(
  SELECT DT = DATEADD(SECOND,i.N,@startdate)
  FROM       iTally AS i
)
SELECT TOP (2000)
  DT         = c.DT,
  InProgress = COUNT(r.rideId)
FROM      Calendar AS c
LEFT JOIN @ride    AS r ON c.DT BETWEEN r.RideStart AND r.RideEnd
GROUP BY  c.DT;
```

**This returns:**

```
DT                        InProgress
------------------------- -----------
2019-01-01 06:00:00.000   0
2019-01-01 06:00:01.000   1
2019-01-01 06:00:02.000   1
2019-01-01 06:00:03.000   1
2019-01-01 06:00:04.000   2
2019-01-01 06:00:05.000   2
...                       
2019-01-01 06:02:15.000   3
2019-01-01 06:02:16.000   3
...                       
2019-01-01 06:02:47.000   4
2019-01-01 06:02:48.000   4
2019-01-01 06:02:49.000   4
...                       
2019-01-01 06:14:17.000   2
2019-01-01 06:14:18.000   2
2019-01-01 06:14:19.000   2
2019-01-01 06:14:20.000   1
2019-01-01 06:14:21.000   1
```

Adding logic for "rides started" should be easy from here. I was going to do it but ran out of time.